# Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<>

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6, angular-ngselect

```
enter code here


    getHospital(term: string = null): Observable<Hospitals[]> {
    let items = this.getHospitals1();
    if (term) {
      items = items.filter(x => x.name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1);

    }
    return items.pipe(delay(500));;
  }



getHospitals1() : Observable<Hospitals[]>{

     return this.http.get<Hospitals[]>('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/monsterbrain/FakeJsonServer/hospitals')

   }
```

**Here an error occured when i add filter** 
It is code for  dropdownlist using ng-select .it is based on text based seraching
here iam using angular7 and rxjs 6

Answer (score 6):

To use `filter` operator you need to use it inside `pipe()`:

```
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

if (term) {
  items = items.pipe(
    filter(x => x.name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1),
  );
}
```